# How to Change the Default Symfony Web Server Host and Port

Tags: symfony, symfony-cli

I'm trying to configure the Symfony web server to listen on a custom host (0.0.0.0) and port (e.g., 8080) instead of the default `127.0.0.1:8000`. However, despite making changes to the configuration, the Symfony server continues to use the default host and port settings.

Here's what I've done:

1. I modified the `.env` file to include the following lines:

   ```
   APP_ENV=dev

   APP_SECRET=SECRET

   APP_HOST=0.0.0.0

   APP_PORT=8080
   ```
2. I've run `symfony server:stop` to ensure there are no conflicts with any previous instances of the server.
3. When I run `symfony server:start`, I get the following output:

   Web server listening
   The Web server is using PHP CGI 8.2.4
   https://127.0.0.1:8000

Despite specifying the custom host and port in the `.env` file, it doesn't seem to be taking effect. The server continues to listen on the default `127.0.0.1:8000`.

How can I change the default Symfony web server host and port to use the custom settings (0.0.0.0:8080) defined in the `.env` file?

Are there any additional configurations or commands I need to use to ensure that Symfony recognizes and uses the custom host and port settings?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony CLI version 5.7.0 (c)

At least, you can specify port on CLI

```
symfony server:start --port=8080
```

Comment: it's the web host server and port  i want to change from it default which is 127.0.0.1:8000. i want to change it to 0.0.0.0:8080. and when i run the command you suggested , Nothing change